# Issue in C# singleton with multi threading: a variable not intialized

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton

This is a simplified version of production code and running in **multi thread** with **singleton**. **Compared to traditional singleton the additional thing is that I initialized client in the `lock` section.**

When I trying to get the client by: `Client client = Singleton.Instance.GetClient();`, there is chance that `client` can be null (**but the chance is very small**).

```
public class Client
{
    public int Value { get; set; } = 10;
}

public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();
    private Client client = null;

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Singleton();
                        
                        // Here is the interesting part!
                        instance.InitClient();
                    }
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private void InitClient()
    {
        this.client = new Client();
    }

    public Client GetClient()
    {
        return this.client;
    }
}
```

This is how I testing it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input thread count: ");
        int threadCount = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Trim());
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(threadCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoStuff()));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
    }

    private static void DoStuff()
    {
        Client client = Singleton.Instance.GetClient();
        if (client.Value != 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}.");
        }
    }
```

And client can be null in occasionlly:
[image: error image]

But when I moved the `InitClient()` into the private constructor of `Singleton`, I never meet the situation that client is null:

```
private Singleton()
{
    this.InitClient();
}
```

I don't have any clue what is difference and what is wrong, thanks for the helping!

Comment: https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton

Comment: You should make `instance` volatile.

Comment: Have a look at the [`Lazy<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1) class. It does only one thing, lazy initialization, and does it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you call instance = new Singleton() inside the lock, "instance" is no longer null, meaning separate (threaded) calls to Singleton.Instance returns immediately, and a call to GetClient on that instance would be a race condition with the InitClient from the first call.

Initializing inside the constructor ensures "Instance" itself is initialized as soon as it's created. So subsequent calls from separate threads wouldn't race against anything.